# How can I improve this Node.js file's routing?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Being new to `Node.js`, I'd like to know of a better way of implementing this:

```
server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {
if (req.url === '/') {
        fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, page) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write(page);
            res.end();
        });
}   
 else if (req.url == '/new.html') { 
        fs.readFile('new.html', function(err, page) {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                res.write(page);
                res.end();
        });
}
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Using something like this:

```
var Url = require('url')
...

// In request handler
var uri = Url.parse(req.url);
switch (uri.pathname) {
  case "/":
    ..
  case "/new.html":
    ..
}
```

Comment: Use a router like express.

Comment: Other than using a framework...

Comment: If you want static routing you can write a naive static router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you wanna implement a static server?
If so, you can just use [connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) and its built-in *static* middlewave. With it, you just need to write the following code to implement a static server:

```
var connect = require("connect");

connect(
    connect.static(__dirname)
).listen(3000);
```

That's it.